# Azure Kubernetes service timed out with 500 status code on API call

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have Java spring boot service deployed on Azure kubernetes service, pod and service are up but not able to see any logs apart from application startup log, and on Calling of API getting 500 internal server error with the Message :
"**A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond :**"

Don't really know what am I missing. Any leads will be helpful.

[image]

Comment: This error is more generic, you need to add more details

Comment: "on Calling of API" from inside or outside the cluster?

Comment: Can you explain how is the basic structure of the application? Are you using ingress controller or service with type load balancer? The error generally happens when the port specified in service does not match with the port at which pod is listening to.

Comment: @CSharpRocks API call is been made from a webApp hosted on Azure webApp in same subscription with no firewall setting

Comment: @Atul I did not what does you mean by structure of application, it is a simple spring boot Application, i am using service with load balancer, and have mention the same port as external port of the service on which my spring application is running.

Comment: @AshutoshMishra - yes, I meant how have you enabled service accessibility from outside (which you explained in the comment). Are you using any service mesh in the cluster (like istio)? If not, this is one of the simplest usecase which should work out of box. If possible can you share sample yaml file which can reproduce this issue for you (remove any sensitive information out of it)?

Comment: @Atul No I am not using any service mesh its vanila approach i am using, i will upload the yaml file in part as its too long for one message and executing that yaml with kubectl apply -f .\deployment.yml command

Comment: screenshot of the yaml attached above

Comment: @AshutoshMishra - Provided few suggestions in answer. Let me know if this does not solve it. If this solves the problem, do accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Basis the screenshot, I have few suggestions -

1. Can you check if you application is listening at port 8081? spring-boot by default listens at port 8080. containerPort does not change the port application is listening to, it just provides a convience mechanism to define it.
2. Can you remove nodePort from service definition? (nodePort is not relevant in case of LoadBalancer).
3. Update the port in service definition to port 80 so that by default application can be accessed without using custom port in the cname of the load balancer.